# If a user checks out 5 copies of book1 and returns 3 returns 2 and then returns 1 more it allows it even if it exceeds the original amount of copies

Tags: python, class, if-statement

## if you choose to return a book at the start of the program, without checking out any books,

## then it won't allow the return (intended). So say the user wants to check out 5/10 copies of

## book1. It checks them out and subtracts them from the copies on shelf. They choose to return

## 3 one day, and 2 another day. (For testing purposes) the day after that, they return another

## copy of book1, which is more than they checked out. It appends it to the book1.borrow aka

## num of copies.   It should not allow the user to return more copies than the original numbr of copies. So this is what I have in my main module. I can add the class LibraryBook if

## needed.

```
from LibraryBook import *

book1 = LibraryBook()
book1.title = "not set"
book1.year = "no se"
book1.author = "set not"
book1.borrow = 10

book2 = LibraryBook()
book2.title = "tes ton"
book2.year = "es on"
book2.author = "ton tes"
book2.borrow = 8

selection = 0
amount = 0
amount1 = 0

while selection != 5:
    print("Select an option")
    print('1 - Borrow a book')
    print('2 - Return a book')
    print('3 - See info on available books')
    print('4 - Exit')
    print()
    selection = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
    print()
    if selection == 1:
        print("Book 1 is: ", book1.title)
        print("Book 2 is: ", book2.title)
        print()
        bookNum = int(input("Enter the book number. "))
        print()
        if bookNum == 1:
            print()
            amount = int(input("Enter the number of copies you would like to check out. "))
            print()
            if (amount <= book1.borrow) and (amount > 0):
                book1.borrowed(amount)
            else:
                print("We only have", book1.borrow, "copies available.")
                print()
        elif bookNum == 2:
            print()
            amount = int(input("Enter the number of copies you would like to check out. "))
            print()
            if (amount <= book2.borrow) and (amount > 0):
                book2.borrowed(amount)
            else:
                print("We only have", book2.borrow, "copies available.")
                print()
        else: 
            print()
            print("That book is not here. Enter 1 or 2. ")
            print()


    if selection == 2:
        print("Book 1 is: ", book1.title)
        print("Book 2 is: ", book2.title)
        print()
        bookNum = int(input("Which book would you like to return? "))
        print()
        if bookNum == 1:
            print()
            amount1 = int(input("Enter the amount of copies you would like to return. "))
            print()
            if amount1 <= amount:
                book1.returned(amount1)
                print()
            elif book1.borrow == book1.borrow:
                print("Invalid number of copies. Count the books and try again ")
                print()
            else:
                print("You only checked out", amount)
                print()
        elif bookNum == 2:
            print()
            amount1 = int(input("Enter the amount of copies you would like to return. "))
            print()
            if amount1 <= amount:
                book2.returned(amount1)
                print()
            elif book2.borrow == book2.borrow:
                print("You did not check out this book.")
                print()
            else:
                print("You only checked out", amount)
                print()
        else: 
            print("Invalid selection. Choose book 1 or book 2.")
            print()
                      

    if selection == 3:
        print()
        print("Book 1:")
        print(book1.__str__())
        print()
        print("Book 2:")
        print(book2.__str__())
        print()

    if (selection <= 0) or (selection >= 5):
        print("Invalid selection. Enter a number 1-4. ")
        print()

    if selection == 4:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not the best programmer but I think I made and example here
Ofc is not the best I made it larger for you to understand, there are some bugs like when asked for book if u give bigger then 2 will break but I let you fix it ;D

```
import sys, os, time, re
class LibraryBook(object):
    def __init__(self, title, year, author, borrow):
        self.title = title
        self.year = year
        self.author = author
        self.borrow = borrow
    def borrow_add(self, amount: int):
        self.borrow += amount
    def left(self):
        return self.borrow
    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
    def borrow_sell(self, amount: int):
        self.borrow -= amount
    def get_book_info(self):
        val = f'''
Book Title: {self.title}
Book Year: {self.year}
Book Author: {self.author}
Left in stock: {self.borrow}
        '''
        return val



book1 = LibraryBook('Prison Break', 2016, 'My House', 8)
book2 = LibraryBook('Hello', 1999, 'NO one', 10)

###########
#That is so you can do book3,4,5 etc.. without write in print all books on hand ;D
books = re.findall('book.', (str(globals().copy())).replace("'", ''))
books_titles = [eval(f'{o}.get_title()') for o in books]
##########
user_lib =[]

#You can use that in a function (def) and call it when you need it
while True:
    os.system('cls')
    option = int(input('''
Select an option
1 - Borrow a book
2 - Return a book
3 - See info on available books
4 - See my lib
5 - Exit
>>> '''))
    if option == 1:
        option_2 = input("\n".join(f"Book{o+1}:{i}" for o, i in enumerate(books_titles))+'\nWhat book(ex: 1):')
        option_3 = int(input('How much?: '))
        if int(eval(f'book{option_2}.left()'))-option_3 >= 0: 
            if x:=list(filter(lambda book: book['name'] == eval(f'book{option_2}.title'), user_lib)):
                user_lib[user_lib.index(x[0])]['amount'] +=option_3
            else:
                user_lib.append({'name': eval(f'book{option_2}.get_title()'), 'amount': option_3})
            print(f'You borrowed {option_3} books')
            eval(f'book{option_2}.borrow_sell({option_3})') #Remove from store
        else:
            print(f'We have {eval(f"book{option_2}.left()")} books left...')
        time.sleep(1) # wait 1 second for user to read then reset

    elif option == 2:
        option_2 = input("\n".join(f"Book{o+1}:{i}" for o, i in enumerate(books_titles))+'\nWhat book(ex: 1):')
        if len(x:=list(filter(lambda book: book['name'] == eval(f'book{option_2}.get_title()'), user_lib))) > 0:
            option_3 = int(input('How much?: '))
            if user_lib[pos:=user_lib.index(x[0])]['amount'] -option_3 >= 0:
                user_lib[pos]['amount'] -= option_3
                if user_lib[pos]['amount'] == 0:
                    user_lib.pop(pos)
                print(f'You returned {option_3} books')
                eval(f'book{option_2}.borrow_add({option_3})') # Add them back to shop
            else:
                print(f"You don't have enogh books, you have only: {x[0]['amount']}")
            time.sleep(1) # wait 1 second for user to read then reset
        else:
            print("You don't any books of thta kind")
        time.sleep(1)
    elif option == 3:
        option_2 = input("\n".join(f"Book{o+1}:{i}" for o, i in enumerate(books_titles))+'\nWhat book(ex: 1):')
        print(eval(f'book{option_2}.get_book_info()'))
        input('Press enter to continue...')
    elif option == 4:
        print("\n".join(f"Book Name:{user_lib[o]['name']}\nAmount I have:{user_lib[o]['amount']}" for o, i in enumerate(user_lib)) if user_lib != [] else "You don't have any books")
    elif option == 5:
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print('Invalid number')
    time.sleep(1) # wait 1 second for user to read then reset
```